# Problem accessing user uploaded video in temporary memory

Tags: python, django, youtube

I'm trying to submit a user uploaded video to youtube using an html input type `file` and the python module youtube-upload.  When the form is submitted it is handled like so:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    video = request.FILES['file']

    v=str(video)

    command = 'youtube-upload --email=email@gmail.com --password=password --title=title --description=description --category=Sports ' + v

    r = subprocess.Popen(command,   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    v = r.stdout.read()
```

So I would assume the problem is that I need to provide a more complete path for the video.  If this is the case, what is the path to access the video in temporary memory.

The generic for of the command is: 
`youtube-upload --email=email --password=password --title=title --description=description --category=category video.avi`

Alternatively, I've looked at the youtube api specifically [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#uploading_videos) but if anyone could provide a more complete explanation of how to do this in python using the api that would be amazing. Unfortunately, the guide on the site just focuses on the xml.

EDIT FOLLOWING sacabuche's COMMENT:

so my view is now roughly:

```
def upload_video(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         video = request.FILE['file']
         v = video.temporary_file_path
         command = 'youtube-upload --email=email@gmail.com --password=password --title=title --description=description --category=Sports ' + v   

         r=subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

         vid = r.stdout.read()
     else:
         form = VideoForm()
         request.upload_handlers.pop(0)
     return render_to_response('create_check.html', RequestContext(request, locals() ) )
```

but `v=video.temporary_file_path` draws the error `'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'temporary_file_path'`. So video is still in temporary memory and I don't know what object `temporary_file_path` is suppose to be called on or how to get said object.

Comment: have you changed your FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact django save the files on memory, but **large files** are saved in a path.
The size of "large file" can be defined in settings using `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`
and
The `FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS`  by default are:

```
("django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler",
 "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler",)
```

And this give us 2 possibilities:

## 1. Remove the memory handler

Remove the `..MemoryFileUploadHandler` but all your files will be saved in a temp file and this is not cool

## 2. Modify the handlers on the fly

[docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#modifying-upload-handlers-on-the-fly)

```
#views.py

def video_upload(request):
    # this removes the first handler (MemoryFile....)
    request.upload_handlers.pop(0)
    return _video_upload(request)

def _video_upload(request):
    ....
```

To get the file path you just need to do `video.temporary_file_path`

Comment: all this is written in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads)